# Using torch.distributed.all_reduce to eval

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI4Ik.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DY0x.png)
I add an online eval function in my training process, and this bug caused by dist.all_reduce only occurs after the eval function has been called many times.

and after I delete this eval function, this code can finish the training process.
cuda version:11.4, NCCL version 2.10.3,while I check their compatibility on nvidia[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq2R7.png)
And I do not know how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!